# Integrity constraint violation error when inserting data into a table that has a foreign Key

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3

I have two tables in the database :

apartments table

id | user_id | Location

agents table

id | name | email | town

I have created a relationship between the two table in their respective models as below :

Apartment Model:

```
public function agent(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Agent');
}
```

Agent Model :

```
 public function apartments()
 {
   return $this->hasMany('App\Apartment');
 }
```

When I fill in a form to post data into the apartments table I get this error :

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null 
(SQL: insert into `apartments` (`user_id`, `Photo`, `Location`, `Size`, `Bedrooms`, `MasterBedrooms`,
 `Unitdetails`, `Housedetails`, `Rent`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, 1497870161.jpg, Nairobi,
 One bedroom, 1, 0, unit, house, 12000, 2017-06-19 11:02:42, 2017-06-19 11:02:42))

This is my controller :

```
class ApartmentController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request){
        //Validating the data
        $this->validate($request, array(
            'Photo'=>'required|image',
            'Location'=>'required|max:255',
            'Size'=>'required',
            'Bedrooms'=>'required',
            'MasterBedrooms'=>'required',
            'Unitdetails'=>'required',
            'Housedetails'=>'required',
            'Rent'=>'required',
        ));

        //Store data into DB
        $apartment = new Apartment;
        $apartment->user_id = Auth()->id();
        // $house->Photo = $request->Photo;
        //Saving the photo
        $image = $request->file('Photo');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $location = public_path('images/' . $filename);
        Image::make($image)->resize(735, 460)->save($location);
        $apartment->Photo = $filename;

        $apartment->Location = $request->Location;
        $apartment->Size = $request->Size;
        $apartment->Bedrooms = $request->Bedrooms;
        $apartment->MasterBedrooms = $request->MasterBedrooms;
        $apartment->Unitdetails = $request->Unitdetails;
        $apartment->Housedetails = $request->Housedetails;
        $apartment->Rent = $request->Rent;

        $apartment->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'Sent successfully!');

        return redirect::back();
    }
}
```

This my migration to add foreign key to the apartments table:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('apartments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->after('id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('agents');
        });
    }
```

The user_id in the apartments table should come from the agents table or should be the agent id in the agents table.

What I'm I missing?

Comment: The error seems quite clear. You have a column in the table that cannot take on a NULL value. Make sure you are logged in as a user.

Comment: The error shows while logged in. I have three accounts, user, agent and admin. The error show when I fill in a form in the agents account while logged in.

Comment: try `Auth::id()` instead of `Auth()->id()` in your controller file.

Comment: In the error message, it shows there isn't a value for the user_id column in the insert statement. So either @amit answer or auth->id().

Comment: @amit I have tried Auth::id() and the error persists.

Comment: The user_id should come from the agents table not the laravel's default users table.